# Swift - textfield not fit in canvas

Tags: ios, uitextfield, autolayout, xcode6

My textfield doesn't fit in my canvas. Below is my app image. How I can rectify this problem? I already add constraints but still not fit after I run it in my mobile phone (iPhone5).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Remove the constraint that sets the width of the text field.
2. Add a constraint for **"Leading Space to Superview"**.
   To do this, control drag from just inside the left edge of your text field to the edge of the view.  Choose **Leading Space to Container Margin** from the pop-up.

[image: Control dragging to set the constraint]

[image: Constraint Pop Up]

4. Add a constraint for **"Training Space to Superview"**.
   To do this, control drag from just inside the right edge of your text field to the edge of the view.  Choose **Trailing Space to Container Margin** from the pop-up.

Now your `UITextField` will stretch to any size screen.

[image: Constraints Set]